# How do I calculate the Jacobian matrix of the transformation of a 1-m manifold to a chart (topology question)?

Tags: general-topology, matrices

What I want to do is take a 1-m manifold (something like a circle), and transform a subset of that manifold into a chart. I want to represent that function from manifold to chart with a 1 x 1 matrix, and find the Jacobian determinant of the matrix. I know that it will involve a derivative (how do I calculate the derivative?) and that if the determinant is positive, the manifold is orientable, if it is negative, it is not orientable.

I want to show that the manifold is orientable. Please give guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so in general, it doesn't make sense to talk about the derivative of a map from a manifold in quantitative terms. When trying to determine orientability, you need to calculate the Jacobian of the transition maps between charts $U_1 \to M \to U_2$, where $U_1, U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are the neighborhoods of the charts.

One other point: we refer to $1$-manifolds when we want one dimension, and $m$-manifolds when we want to consider arbitrary dimension.

EDIT: For example, consider the charts on $S^1$ (the circle) given by stereographic projection. We have $$\phi_1: S^1 - \{N\} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$\phi_2: S^1 - \{S\} \to \mathbb{R}$$ 
Where $N = (0,1), S = (0,-1)$ are the north and south poles. The transition map is $$\phi_1 \circ \phi^{-1}_2: \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}  $$
Given simply by $x \mapsto 1/x$. The Jacobian at a point $x$ is thus simply the derivative: $-1/x^2$. This at first appears problematic, as we have negative jacobian, but actually since we have twp charts and the Jacobian is *consistently* negative, we simply reverse the orientation of one chart.

Comment: Good answer, but how do I calculate the Jacobian of the transformation. Does it still involve derivatives?

Comment: Of course. For most cases where orientability is being checked by hand you manually put a set of charts on the manifold and can explicitly write out the transition map $\tau:U_1 \to U_2$. Then you take the derivative(s) and compute the Jacobian.

Comment: So how would I go about computing the Jacobian?